# How to open python program in another window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

So im using windows 10 and python39 and im trying to make a program with two windows. But when I use `os.system('python program2.py --someargs')` it opens in the same window as the launcher.
How can I open it in another window?
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrxKd.png)

Comment: Replace "window" with "console" and restart your research.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subprocess module:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call('python file.py --someargs', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Did a little bit of digging and found this and in my testing, it works fine!

[@CALISVALIS1010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14743267/calisvalis1010),
If you have a while loop in the other file and want to do things simultaneously, you can always import threading and spawn the subprocess in another thread like so,

```py
import threading
import subprocess

threading.Thread(target=lambda: subprocess.call('python file.py --someargs', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)).start()
```

Comment: It works but i have a 'while True' in second file and only if i close second file first file executes.

Comment: @cal That's a different issue, and you may want to research that issue yourself. If you cannot find a solution, you could ask a question, although keep in mind that we do assume a minimum familiarity with the problem domain. You should be able to know what a loop does.